# Custom sort order for an enum field

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Is it possible to change alphabetical sorting in JPA to self defined?

I have this data in column `division`:

```
BRONZE
SILVER
GOLD
DIAMOND
```

And I have mapped this to an entity field:

```
public enum Division {
    BRONZE,
    SILVER,
    GOLD,
    DIAMOND
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Division division;

  ...
}
```

If I use default sorting I get an alphabetical order:

- **B**RONZE
- **D**IAMOND
- **G**OLD
- **S**ILVER

But I want to have sorting by quality of ore (in the order of the enum).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorting (or ordering) takes place on the database level. So it is not possible to define a custom `Comparator` or similar - if that was your intention. Instead the database will need to know the *quality* somehow to use it as order criteria.

**One option** is to sort by the ordinal of the enum. That is only possible if you store it in the DB - instead of the name:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) // The default
private Division division;
```

**A second option** is to convert the `enum` to an `Entity` and store the quality as new integer field explicitly. The disadvantage of that is, that you can't use constant values any more.

**A third option** is a `Formula` field with the explicit *name to quality* mapping (you can order by formula fields as well):

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Division division;

@Formula("case division when 'BRONZE' then 0 when 'SILVER' then 1 ... end")
private int divisionQuality;
```

This is the slowest option - if you have many rows in your table.

Comment: Is it possbile to sort by the @Formula column, using criteriaQuery?

Comment: Yes it is, that was the intention of my post. I've created a Formula more than once especially for sorting (I mean for much more complex expressions). If you enable or emulate the bytecode enhancement you can even mark the formula as `LAZY`, in which case the formula is used for sorting _only_.

Answer (score 2):

I use an order on my enum values like this:

```
@Getter
public enum MyEnum {
   VAL1(1),
   VAL2(2),
   VAL3(3);

   private final int sortOrder;

   MyEnum(int sortOrder) {
       this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
   }
}
```

And then CriteriaBuilder.Case to sort results:

```
CriteriaBuilder.Case<Integer> selectCase = cb.selectCase();
for (MyEnum value : MyEnum.values()) {
    selectCase.when(cb.equal(root.get(Object_.enumProperty), cb.literal(value)),
            value.getSortOrder());
}
selectCase.otherwise(4);
if (direction.isAscending()) {
    order = cb.asc(selectCase);
} else {
    order = cb.desc(selectCase);
}
query.orderBy(order);
```

Comment: Nice! Even when the enum doesn't have a sortOrder field and you can't add one, you can still use this approach with `MyEnum.values()` (which returns the values in the order that they were declared). You would have to increment and int in the body of the for loop.

Comment: Using Postgres, I tried to get `array_position(array['VAL1'::char, 'VAL2'::char, 'VAL3'::char], value::char)` to work with the JPA Criteria API - to no avail. Your solution is nicer in that it's independent of Postgres's array_position function.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom query like this, to order the enum as needed:

```
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e ORDER BY (CASE WHEN e.enumField = 'ENUM_VALUE' THEN 0 else 1 END)")
List<Entity> findAllInOrder();
```

Comment: The `@Query` annotation is only available in Spring Data JPA, not in plain JPA.